# Get yesterdays date and if Monday get weekend range

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to get yesterdays date. If the current date is monday I need three dates returned - Sunday, Saturday and Friday. Is there any way possible to accomplish this in a single query. I don't know VBA that well but if that is the only way to solve I am willing to get my hands dirty.

```
Select * from [Purchase Order] where MyDate = 'Yesterdays date(s)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WeekDay()` function will tell you whether today's date, as returned by the  `Date()` function, is Monday.  Use that in an `IIf()` expression so that `MyDate` matches yesterday's date when today is not Monday, or the previous 3 dates when `MyDate` is Monday.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [Purchase Order] AS p
WHERE
    IIf(Weekday(Date()) = 2,
        p.MyDate BETWEEN DateAdd('d',-3,Date())
            AND DateAdd('d',-1,Date()),
        p.MyDate=DateAdd('d',-1,Date())
        );
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.  After posting that answer I wondered what should happen if the query is run on a weekend.  It's OK if only run on weekdays.