# Get yesterdays date and if Monday get weekend range for SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get yesterdays date and if the current date is Monday I would need Sunday, Saturday and Friday. This is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907162/get-yesterdays-date-and-if-monday-get-weekend-range) for ms access. I now need this for SQL server. How would I go about this?

Will create an inline view that will return the previous date in SQL It will return between 1 and 3 rows depending on the current date.

If current date is Monday Return:

```
Sundays date
Saturdays date
Fridays date
```

- If current date is Tuesday then Return:  Mondays date
- If current date is Wednesday then  Return:  Tuesdays date
- If current date is Thursday then Return:  Wednesdays date
- If current date is  Friday then Return:  Thursdays date
- If current date is Saturday then  Return:  Fridays date
- If current date is Sunday then Return:  Saturdays date

I hope this helps explain what I am trying to do more clearly.

sample select query

```
--get previous date
select * from [Purchase Orders] where MyDate in (previous date(s))
```

Comment: How about use `DATEADD`?

Comment: So it would return one value if it was any other day, but 3 if it was Monday? What would you return it to, exactly?

Comment: The column's data type is DATETIME[2] or DATE ?

Comment: I will make the question more clear

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear about the question though. But you can do something on the similar lines.
Using `DATEPART` and `DATEADD`

```
DECLARE @TodaysDate DATETIME
SET @TodaysDate = '2013-04-10'


SELECT CASE 
     WHEN DATEPART (DW, DATEADD (DD, -1, @TodaysDate )) IN (1, 6, 7) 
     THEN 'WeekEnd' ELSE 'WeekDay' 
     END D
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the query you linked to, you can try the code below:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Purchase Order] 
 WHERE MyDate >= CASE 
                     WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE() , 112)) LIKE 'Monday' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE()), 112)
                     ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 112)
                 END 
   AND MyDate < CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnPreviousDay (@suppliedDate DATE)
RETURNS @PreviousDates TABLE (PreviousDate DATE)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @PreviousDates (
        PreviousDate)
    SELECT
        PreviousDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @suppliedDate)

    IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, @@DATEFIRST - 1, @suppliedDate)) = 1 -- If Monday
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @PreviousDates (
            PreviousDate)
        SELECT
            PreviousDate = DATEADD(DAY, -2, @suppliedDate)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            PreviousDate = DATEADD(DAY, -3, @suppliedDate)

    END

    RETURN

END
```

You can use it like this:

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    dbo.ufnPreviousDay('2018-03-19') AS T

/*
Result:
    2018-03-18
    2018-03-17
    2018-03-16
*/
```

If you want today's previous dates:

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN dbo.ufnPreviousDay(GETDATE()) AS M ON T.MyDate = M.PreviousDate
```